# Trying to precheck check boxes in bootstrap vue

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, bootstrap-vue

I am using the following code for my input:

```
<b-form-checkbox
              v-for="option in suggestedGroups"
              v-model="selected"
              :key="option.item"
              :value="option"
              name=""
              checked
            >
```

But despite the `checked` flag, the checkboxes come up empty

Comment: You're binding multiple checkboxes to the same property, `selected`. They will overwrite each other when selecting another checkbox. If that's the intent, you should use [radio buttons](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-radio#form-radio-inputs) instead.

Comment: selected is defined as an array, and mutiple choices have been effective. My only problem is that I can't seem to generate the form with them all preselected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a checked checkbox. You need to set the `v-model` to the same value as the checkbox you want checked.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      selected: 2,
      options: [
        { value: 1, text: 'Value 1' },
        { value: 2, text: 'Value 2' },
        { value: 3, text: 'Value 3' }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-form-checkbox v-model="selected" v-for="option in options" :key="option.value" :value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
  </b-form-checkbox>
</div>
```

Comment: I want all of them to be checked. Selected is an array, but the choices and checkboxes are dynamic, so I am not sure how to hard code them in the data object

Comment: This answer helped me figure this out. Selected is an array. When I define the choices, I simply set selected to include all of them in the array.  Thanks.